# Quiero activar el boton de "Imprimir" luego de que se envíe el formulario, sin recargar la página. AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, formularios

En este caso, ya cuento con la parte del código de AJAX donde me permite enviar el formulario y guardar la información en DB sin que se recargue la página. Sin embargo, no he logrado realizar el condicional dentro del AJAX en la parte del SUCESS para activar el botón de Imprimir. Les comparto el div de los botones y el Script de AJAX:

Div de botones:

```
<div class="card-footer" id="result">
    <input id="enviar" type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success"></input>
    <a onclick="history.back()" class="btn btn-outline-danger no-print">Cancelar</a>
    <button id="imp" disabled onclick="window.print()" class="btn btn-outline-dark no-print">Imprimir</button>
</div>
```

Script AJAX:

```
<script>
                $("#enviar").click(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "cod/Historial/actadev",
                        type: "post",
                        data: $("#formActaDev").serialize(),
                        success: function(resultado) {
                            $("#result").html(resultado);
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Añado el formulario completo:

```
<form id="formActaDev" autocomplete="off" method="post">
                <section class="content">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <table class="table table-striped">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="6"><img align="right" src="<?= base_url() ?>img/logo.png" width="111" class="img-square">
                                                        <h4><b>Acta de Devolución de Equipo de Cómputo</b></h4>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="6" align="center"><b>DATOS DEL COLABORADOR</b></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><b>Nombre:</b></td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" align="center"><b><?= $acta->NombreEmpleado;  ?></b></td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><b>Empresa:</b></td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" align="center"><b><?= $acta->NombreCliente;  ?></b></td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><b>Dominio:</b></td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" align="center"><b><?= $acta->Dominio;  ?></b></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><b>Correo:</b></td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" align="center"><b><?= $acta->CorreoEmpleado;  ?></b></td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><b>Autorizó:</b></td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" align="center"><b><?= $acta->PAutorizada;  ?></b></td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><b>Teléfono/Ext:</b></td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" align="center"><b><?= $acta->TelefonoEmpleado;  ?></b></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td colspan="6"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="6" align="center"><b>ESPECIFICACIONES DEL EQUIPO DEVUELTO</b></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="2" align="center"><b>TIPO</b></td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" align="center"><b>NOMBRE DEL EQUIPO</b></td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" align="center"><b>MARCA</b></td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" align="center"><b>MODELO</b></td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" align="center"><b>SERIAL</b></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="2" align="center"><?= $acta->Tipo;  ?></td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" align="center"><?= $acta->SerialInterno;  ?></td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" align="center"><?= $acta->IDMarca;  ?></td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" align="center"><?= $acta->Modelo;  ?></td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" align="center"><?= $acta->SerialOriginal;  ?></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="2" align="center"><b>PROCESADOR</b></td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="2" align="center"><b>RAM</b></td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="2" align="center"><b>ALMACENAMIENTO</b></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="2" align="center"><?= $acta->Precesador;  ?></td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="2" align="center"><?= $acta->RAM;  ?></td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="2" align="center"><?= $acta->Almacenamiento;  ?></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="6" align="center"><b>DESCRIPCIÓN DE ACCESORIOS/SERIAL</b></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="6">
                                                        <table class="table table-striped">
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <?php
                                                                foreach ($accesorio as $ac) {
                                                                ?>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td style="border: 1px solid black;" align="center"><?= $ac->Nombre;  ?></td>
                                                                        <td style="border: 1px solid black;" align="center"><?= $ac->SerialInterno;  ?></td>
                                                                        <td style="border: 1px solid black;" align="center"><?= $ac->SerialOriginal;  ?></td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                <?php
                                                                }
                                                                ?>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="6" align="center"><b>OBSERVACIONES</b></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="6" align="center"><?= $acta->Observ;  ?></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td colspan="6"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="6" align="center"><b>DESCRIPCIONES DE DEVOLUCIÓN</b></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="6" align="center"><b>EVALUACIÓN DE COMPONENTES DEVUELTOS </b></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="3" rowspan="7">OTRA PARTE</td>
                                                    <th style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="1"><b>TAPAS Y BORDES</b></th>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="1">
                                                        <select class="form-control" style="width:100%" name="TapBord" required>
                                                            <option selected disabled value="">Estado del componente</option>
                                                            <option>EN BUEN ESTADO</option>
                                                            <option>CON NOVEDAD</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="1"><input class="form-control" style="width:100%" name="ObsTapBord" placeholder="OBSERVACIONES"></input></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="1"><b>TECLADO</b></th>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="1">
                                                        <select class="form-control" style="width:100%" name="Teclado" required>
                                                            <option selected disabled value="">Estado del componente</option>
                                                            <option>EN BUEN ESTADO</option>
                                                            <option>CON NOVEDAD</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="1"><input class="form-control" style="width:100%" name="ObsTeclado" placeholder="OBSERVACIONES"></input></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="1"><b>TOUCHPAD</b></th>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="1">
                                                        <select class="form-control" style="width:100%" name="Touchpad" required>
                                                            <option selected disabled value="">Estado del componente</option>
                                                            <option>EN BUEN ESTADO</option>
                                                            <option>CON NOVEDAD</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="1"><input class="form-control" style="width:100%" name="ObsTouchpad" placeholder="OBSERVACIONES"></input></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="1"><b>CÁMARA WEB</b></th>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="1">
                                                        <select class="form-control" style="width:100%" name="CamaraWeb" required>
                                                            <option selected disabled value="">Estado del componente</option>
                                                            <option>EN BUEN ESTADO</option>
                                                            <option>CON NOVEDAD</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="1"><input class="form-control" style="width:100%" name="ObsCamaraWeb" placeholder="OBSERVACIONES"></input></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="1"><b>BLUETOOTH Y WIFI</b></th>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="1">
                                                        <select class="form-control" style="width:100%" name="BlueWifi" required>
                                                            <option selected disabled value="">Estado del componente</option>
                                                            <option>EN BUEN ESTADO</option>
                                                            <option>CON NOVEDAD</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="1"><input class="form-control" style="width:100%" name="ObsBlueWifi" placeholder="OBSERVACIONES"></input></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="1"><b>SONIDO</b></th>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="1">
                                                        <select class="form-control" style="width:100%" name="Sonido" required>
                                                            <option selected disabled value="">Estado del componente</option>
                                                            <option>EN BUEN ESTADO</option>
                                                            <option>CON NOVEDAD</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="1"><input class="form-control" style="width:100%" name="ObsSonido" placeholder="OBSERVACIONES"></input></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="1"><b>CARGADOR</b></th>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="1">
                                                        <select class="form-control" style="width:100%" name="Cargador" required>
                                                            <option selected disabled value="">Estado del componente</option>
                                                            <option>EN BUEN ESTADO</option>
                                                            <option>CON NOVEDAD</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="1"><input class="form-control" style="width:100%" name="ObsCargador" placeholder="OBSERVACIONES"></input></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="6" align="center"><b>ACLARACIONES Y DEBERES</b></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="6"><?= $acta->Aclaraciones;  ?></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td colspan="6"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="6" align="center"><b>CONSTANCIA DE DEVOLUCION</b></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="3" align="center"><b>USUARIO QUIEN DEVUELVE</b></td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="3" align="center"><b>PERSONAL SINAPPTIC</b></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="1"><b>Nombre:</b></td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="2" align="center"><b><?= $acta->NombreEmpleado;  ?></b></td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="1"><b>Nombre:</b></td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="2" align="center"><b><?= $this->session->userdata('NombreEmpleado') ?></b></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="1"><b>Firma y D.I:</b></td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="2"><b></b></td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="1"><b>Firma:</b></td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="2"><b></b></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <?php $Fecha = date('d-m-Y') ?>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="1"><b>Fecha:</b></td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="2" align="center"><b><?= $Fecha ?></b></td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="1"><b>Fecha:</b></td>
                                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="2" align="center"><b><?= $Fecha ?></b></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-footer" id="resultado">
                                        
                                        <button id="enviar" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Enviar</button>
                                        <a onclick="history.back()" class="btn btn-outline-danger no-print">Cancelar</a>
                                        <?php
                                        if ($estado == true){
                                        ?>
                                            <button id="imp" onclick="window.print()" class="btn btn-outline-dark no-print">Imprimir</button>
                                        <?php
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </section>
            </form>
```

Les quedaré eternamente agradecido cualquier tipo de ayuda o sugerencia. Muchas gracias!!
Les quedaré eternamente agradecido cualquier tipo de ayuda o sugerencia. Muchas gracias!!
Les quedaré eternamente agradecido cualquier tipo de ayuda o sugerencia. Muchas gracias!!
Les quedaré eternamente agradecido cualquier tipo de ayuda o sugerencia. Muchas gracias!!
Les quedaré eternamente agradecido cualquier tipo de ayuda o sugerencia. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: y que se supone que obtienes como respuesta en la peticion ajax?, que es `resultado`?
agrega mas detalles a tu pregunta

Comment: Resultado, simplemente es una función por defecto, no interfiere en la pregunta. Estoy diciendole al ajax, que envíe a través de una función X y lo cargue en el div con id="result"

Comment: Primero `Resultado` no es una funcion es una variable, segundo dices que quieres que con la peticion ajax se habilite el boton pero una peticion de este tipo te puede devolver un `array` vacio, te puede devolver el codigo HTTP o te puede devolver un sin fin de probabilidades, por eso te digo que agregues mas detalles. **De que depende que el boton se habilite?** de que la peticion sea exitosa? (resultado.status==200), que resultado traiga data? (`resultado.data.lenght!==0`)

Comment: Te respondo desde aquí: Lo que sucede, es que el botón debe habilitarse luego de que el formulario se haya enviado, cuando el formulario se haya enviado, el botón imprimir debe habilitarse. Estaba pensando en guardar un estado a través de una variable y que ese estado me dé paso a la activación del botón, pero realmente no lo he podido lograrlo. Añadí el código del formulario.

Comment: Tiene algunas modificaciones que he estado realizando en la parte de los botones, pero aún no me ha funcionado

Comment: Entiendo pero debes analizar que hay dos opciones en cuanto a la peticion `ajax`, puede ser un exito o puede dar un error debes tener claro el comportamiento en ambos casos. pero veo que estas usando `Jquery`,  tambien veo que tu boton tiene el atributo `disabled `, lo que tienes que hacer es usar `jquery` para remover ese atributo de la siguiente forma podria funcionar `$("#imp").removeAttr("disabled")`